# I need to store data(from .csv files) so that it cannot be altered. Using NFTs was proposed to me, is it the best solution?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

So I was given as project where I need to guarantee that some data coming from .csv files cannot be altered using the blockchain. They proposed I use NFTs to do that but is it the best solution ?
The data size is quite small, less than 20 lines probably.

The data should then be accesible through an interface for them to read.

Comment: Why not use IPFS?

Comment: Yes I guess that could also be a solution. Is there any advantage using one or the other ?

Comment: IPFS is a storage protocol, meaning it is specifically designed for storage and nothing else.
There is no gas cost associated with it. Blockchain is not a good option to store data coz you need to pay gas fees.